# Can I get the query that gets executed by the MongoDB Golang driver when collection.Aggregate() executes on a pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, go, pipeline

I'm using the MongoDB driver for Golang.  I have a pipeline setup below.  Is there a way I can see the query that gets executed by the call to `collection.Aggregate()` ala Hibernate?

pipeline := mongo.Pipeline{
{{"$match", bson.D{
{"created_time", bson.D{
{"$lt", primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(expireTimeLimit)}}},
{"archived", bson.D{{"$eq", true}}}},
}}}

aggregateCursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, pipeline)

Comment: What query do you want to see? Those are the exact same stages you'd use in the mongo shell client. Hibernate is an ORM layer over a relational database, which translates queries to SQL. In case of MongoDB, the queries are just JSON-like objects.